# Interpolate two-dimensional numpy array with respect to the periodicity of the values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have points (x, y) with a value (z) which is periodic in pi, i.e. zero is the same as pi. The points are very coarse so I need to interpolate them.

I tried interpolating the values with griddata() from scipy.interpolate which results in the problem.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import numpy as np


N = 1000
grid_res = 1000
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
z = np.ndarray(N)

# calculate some stuff, doesnt really matter
for i in range(0, N):
    if x[i] - 0.5 > 0.:
        z[i] = np.arccos(-(y[i] - .5)/np.sqrt((x[i] - .5)**2 + (y[i] - .5)**2))
    else:
        z[i] = np.pi - np.arccos(-(y[i] - .5)/np.sqrt((x[i] - .5)**2 + (y[i] - .5)**2))

# define grid.
xi = np.linspace(0., 1., grid_res)
yi = np.linspace(0., 1., grid_res)

# interpolate the data on the grid.
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None, :], yi[:, None]), method='linear')

# plot the values
CS = plt.imshow(zi,
                cmap='hsv',
                origin='lower',
                extent=[0., 1., 0., 1.],
                vmax=np.pi,
                vmin=0.)

plt.show()
```

Just interpolating the values linear with griddata results in unwanted behavior:

For example:
[8/10 pi, pi, 2/10 pi,]

Is interpolated to
[8/10 pi, 9/10 pi, pi, 6/10 pi, 2/10 pi.]

I want it to be 
[8/10 pi, 9/10 pi, pi, 1/10 pi, 2/10 pi.]

Is there a way to interpolate those value with respect to their periodicity?